# Delete command button from p-splitbutton (Angular Primeng)

Tags: angular, primeng, split-button

I want to delete the menu button as shown below from the p-splitbutton.
[p-splitbutton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2FV1.png)

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

I tried searching the internet but did not find any way to delete the in-built menu button from the splitbutton. For now, I used css to hide the menubutton element, but I want a permanent solution on how to delete that inbuilt component.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use this button without the menu. Use the default button.

See here:[Button Prime NG](https://primeng.org/button)